# AWS glue rollback strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am doing ETL from oracle RDS to s3. If I am running my ETL script and it is dumping some data in s3 and break in middle of something, how can I rollback my whole script? is there any rollback strategy or configuration aws glue provide?

Comment: No automatic option available on s3. The only option is to create a boto3 client for s3 and call delete api to delete the s3 key/files in case of exception

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Glue doesn't currently support this functionality out of the box. 
This kind of functionality will have to be managed by your scripts and ETL process.  There are a few ways you can achieve this.

- You can build a delta process that compares the data currently in s3 with the new data being loaded via your ETL process using a timestamp field or an incrementing primary key value.  This will give you recoverability so your process can continue where it left off during the next execution.
- If you are moving multiple tables to S3 in a single ETL process, you can break them out to individual processes and have the Glue scheduler chain the jobs together so that you can start where you left off once you have resolved the issue.
- You can build your job so it does a full reload of the datasets to s3 during each execution.  If there is an exception, your data will be fully replaced during the next execution.